# How do I pass Model back up to Controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

The model that is being displayed in my view has been filtered by user action so some of the original data is no longer there. Paying attention to the `ActionLink` for `EditRow`, this is how my view displays the model:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.Weekly.WeekBeginning.ToShortDateString()  -      @item.Weekly.WeekEnding.ToShortDateString()
    </td>
    <td>
        @(item.WeeklyTargetId != ViewBag.Edited ? Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hours) : Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Hours))
    </td>
    <td>
        //here is the line I am trying to pass the model through:
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRow", new {id = item.WeeklyTargetId, currentSelection = Model}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id = item.WeeklyTargetId}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = item.WeeklyTargetId})
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

In the `ActionLink`for `EditRow` I was able to easily pass the id of each item through, but when I added `currentSelection = Model` or even `= Model.ToList()`, the controller method receives a count of 0.

Here is the Action signature I am using:

```
//I've tried IQueryable<WeeklyTarget> as well
public ActionResult EditRow(int? id, List<WeeklyTarget> selection )
```

My question is how can I pass the current(filterd) model being displayed in the view to the controller action? Should I be going about this a different way?

Comment: you're going about it in a somewhat unusual way.  Usually your `Edit` action takes an ID of some sort, and returns the model generated from that ID.  Then the `Edit`'s POST action takes the updated model.

Comment: I've replaced the `Edit` Action with `EditRow`, I intend to update the Hours column in this view rather than navigating to a new page. This works fine, however when I click this button the model reverts to an unfiltered view. I would like the data persisted.

Comment: In the view "currentSelection" should be "selection" in order to match the parameter in your action method. Just my guess from doing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to implement this, but if you MUST do it this way you would be better off passing the Ids from each item in Model rather than the Model objects themselves. Then in the Edit (GET) method, you can get those full objects from the DB using those IDs.

The intention of this code is not clear to me though. If every row has an "Edit" link, then I would assume that clicking that would only care about that specific row and not the entire list. More detail would be helpful to better answer the question.

UPDATE:
As discussed below, the best way to go about this would be with AJAX(recommend using jQuery). Upon click on a edit link, you should initiate a click handler in JS:

```
$(".editLink").click(function(){
   //Code Here
});
```

The logic for the click function will be to grab the data from the row and make an AJAX Post back to a controller action.

```
$.post(urlToAction, data, succuessFunction);
```

This will work perfectly for you, however you will have to do a lot of the data insert, update, delete operations manually. There are some pretty handy JS frameworks out there like Knockout JS which will handle this automatically for you after a little wiring/plumbing work up front.

I suggest you check those out.

Comment: You're correct in assuming I only care about updating that row, specifically the Hours column above the column with the links. I have it change from a display to an editor based on the row that EditRow was clicked on, however, the whole model refreshes and any filters I had on this view is lost, I want it to persist. This is why I want the current model to be passed along with it. It seems this is the wrong way to go about it, what is the correct way?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the whole model refreshes"

Comment: The action returns to the Index page anew basically. Before hand filters are applied to this view and only certain data is displayed but calling this action resends the data without anything persisted, should I be asking how to update only certain parts of the page without having to resend the data? Sounds like I should be using asynchronus js now... is that the right approach?

Comment: Yes, LaRae. AJAX would be the best way to implement partial refreshes/saving of the page. It is possible to do this without AJAX, but it would be more of a pain then it is worth. I updated the answer above with some notes on how to get started.